# strcmp() function not providing expected output

Tags: c, for-loop, c-strings, palindrome, strcmp

I'm new to C. The program is to reverse a string, check if it is palindrome and print the reversed string. Although the reversed string is same as the original string even in the output(output is below the code) strcmp() function is giving the wrong output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char ch[n];
    scanf("%s",&ch);
    n=strlen(ch);
    char temp[n];
    int k=0;
    for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        temp[k]=ch[i];
        k+=1;
    }
    int l=strcmp(ch,temp);
    printf("%d\n",l);
    if(l==0)
    printf("PALINDROME\n");
    else
    printf("NOT PALINDROME\n");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("%c",temp[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT 1

```
6
nitin
1
NOT PALINDROME
nitin
```

OUTPUT 2

```
100
nitin
1
NOT PALINDROME
►p@PduV⌡ uVP8a■╚   ■ ☺Σ┼uT╠└a ╠a■ä☺a■╨@↕α@↕αè9Å¥uVP½uZFuVP╬a■░nitin
```

Comment: Your string isn't big enough. You need `char ch[n+1]` to allow room for the null terminator.

Comment: You have a buffer overflow, since an array of size 5 cannot store the string "nitin" (which includes a terminating 0-byte.

Comment: And you also need to add a null terminator to `temp`

Comment: @Barmar I tried that, the only change was in the value of 'l', it became 1 from -1, I'll post those outputs too

Comment: Try adding the option `-fsanitize=address` to the compiler and linker invocations (assuming you're using gcc).

Answer (score 2):

For starters instead of

```
 scanf("%s",&ch);
            ^^^
```

you have to write

```
 scanf("%s",ch);
```

The array `temp` does not contain a string. So this call of `strcmp`

```
int l=strcmp(ch,temp);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

You need to append the array `temp` with the terminating zero character `'\0'` after the for loop like

```
temp[k] = '\0';
```

To do that you need to declare the array like

```
n=strlen(ch);
char temp[n + 1];
```

Comment: There is a stray bracket: `temp[[k] = '\0';`. Also OP has not made `temp` big enough to hold the null terminator - it should be declared as `char temp[n+1];` (`n` being the length of the input string).

Comment: @IanAbbott There is no need to declare the array temp having n + 1 elements because the array ch has n elements. n is not the length of the input string. It is the size of the array ch.

Comment: No, `n` is reassigned `n=strlen(ch);` before the declaration of `temp`. Admittedly, OP edited that line in after your answer though. :-)

Comment: @IanAbbott Oh, thanks, I did not see this. I will update the post.